# Prevent search engines from indexing script URLs

Tags: robots.txt

How to prevent search engines from indexing script URLs like:

domain.tld/?[whatever is here]

robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /?
```

does seem to work.

But still to allow indexing of the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the URL-encoded "?" (`%3D`)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /%3D
```

source: http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt